# How do I disable pull-to-refresh in SOTI Surf?

Tags: android, soti

I have a webpage that is displayed using the SOTI Surf restricted browser, and have a requirement to disable the pull-to-refresh browser functionality.

To do this, I tried to add this CSS to the webpage:

```css
body {
    overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
```

This works good in Chrome, both in the browser and as an Android PWA, but doesn't take effect in SOTI Surf. When that didn't work, I also tried to add a listener for the `beforeunload` event to prevent automatic refreshing, and once again it worked in Chrome but not SOTI Surf.

What's the best way to go about disabling the pull-to-refresh functionality in SOTI Surf?

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot you can do to disable this on the web side of things without resorting to nasty hacks. The browser doesn't respect the `overscroll-behavior` CSS property, and it also doesn't hook the `beforeunload` event.

Starting from Version 15.2, system administrators can [send a legacy script](https://soti.net/mc/help/v14.1/en/console/other/scriptcmds.html) to a MobiControl-enabled device to enable/disable the pull-to-refresh functionality.

```
sendinfo net.soti.action.surf DISABLEPULLTOREFRESH 1
```

To re-enable pull-to-refresh functionality, you can send the same script, but change the `1` to a `0`.